# How to get Children that have same type Kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I have a trouble in Kineticjs, in my code:

```
var G1=new Kinetic.Group()

var sq=new Kinetic.Rect({
x:0,
y:0,
name:"sq"
})
var line1=new Kinetic.Line({
Points:[0,0,10,10],
name:"line1"
})

var line2=new Kinetic.Line({
Points:[0,0,50,50],
name:"line1"
})

G1.add(sq).add(line1).add(line2)
```

I know that to get the children from G1 just type "G1.getChildren()". But to get the children that has same type for example type Kinetic.Line I don't have any idea.
Please help me, tahnks

Comment: Can you iterate the object that you have from `G1.getChildren()` and compare by name?

Comment: Yes i can, but is there any simple way to do it. because I must edit all object that i have crated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for not having a tutorial on this, but you can select children by type like this:

var shapes = layer.get('Line');

in KineticJS, shape types are similar to DOM tags.  You can select them by name.

Answer (score 1):

So the @Grant Timmerman example will work but I'm not sure that for children you can have only shapes so here what I suggest you to do:

```
  var lines = G1.getChildren().filter(function(element) {
    return element instanceof Kinetic.Line;
  });
```

I don't know kinetic very well that's why I'm making that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Shape's `shapeType` property.

Here's an example that gets an array of KineticJS Lines

```
var lines = G1.getChildren().filter(function(element) {
    return element.shapeType === 'Line';
});
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing bug is there only shape types for children?

Comment: What do you mean there are only shape types for children? Maybe I have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I explain it in my answer... maybe I'm making wrong assumption here because I'm not so familiar with kinetic...