# KineticJS group, select children by type

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

How to find type of children in a Kineticjs group?
I am trying to rotate the group if it contains Rect and not if it doesn't.
I have tried Eric's solution from below without luck.
[How to get Children that have same type Kineticjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552329/how-to-get-children-that-have-same-type-kineticjs)

Is there any simplier solution than suggested by @Grant Timmerman and @thinklinux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simpler solution...

```
// test if group1 has at least 1 Rect child

if( group1.get("Rect").length>0 ){ group1.setRotationDeg(45); layer.draw(); }
```

Here's a Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/aCHrh/

Comment: Thanks a ton MarkE for your quick and useful answer. None of the above solutions worked but yours works like a charm. Thank you so much!